# Who voices the small round football sized demon in Good Omens?

Tags: good-omens

There is a small waddling football sized demon in the 2019 Amazon Good Omens series who has a very familiar voice but I couldn't work out who it is from the voice credits. Who does the voice for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to credits from [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1869454/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) - that *waddling football sized demon* is listed as "Hell's Usher" and was voiced by [Andy Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Hamilton). (I remember thinking - "oh - they sound familiar" - realising who it was and thinking it's quite suitable voicing a little demon when one of his most popular works is playing Satan in the Old Harry's Game radio series)

Comment: Ahhh yes! That's him! Knew I recognised that voice!

Comment: Could have sworn it was Phill Jupitus from the voice. But I guess they sound quite similar.